# Strange currents in a lathe

Tags: current-measurement, fft

I am playing with MCSA and Park's Vectors to value motors' health.

As test bed I read currents out of a lathe Spinner TC600, and see something strange: Park's diagram is a snowflake (instead of an approximated circle) and currents are far from sinusoidal waves.

Out of sheer curiosity, is there an "easy" explanation for these graphs? Has it to do with internal inverters? It is not an occasional reading, but what happens when the lathe is on.

[image: screen snapshot]

Comment: Without too much analysis it looks like they may be using TRIAC control rather than PWM (with FETS / IGBTs/Bipolar). So they get segments of source sine waves applied. They can perhaps also transfer any input phase to any desired motor phase at a crossing point so they can reverse direction or polarity if desired. I'm not sure how they get the flat segments - unless fron a rectified DC bus. Knowing even what was used as power switches and how many may help understanding.

Comment: For the curious, I wrote a quick-and-dirt online simulation about how Park's Diagram changes, according to the magnitude of the 5th and 7th harmonics. 
11th and 13th are not taken into account for the sake of simplicity. Press the Play on the left to run, than move the sliders. 
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1KUZmX8pfodiIlSQHz1hwG8h6ohj5Bpoj?usp=sharing

Comment: Looks like fun - can't see how to run it.

Comment: You need to click on the code cell, and a Play dark button will appear on the upper left. Click it and after a few seconds (it needs to load some libraries) you can move the sliders and see how the Park Diagram changes.

Comment: Thanks. You also have to first click the "Playground mode" button at top left. Otherwise it says "Running read only notebooks is not supported. ... ". | Interesting results. It doesn't take much harmonic energy to mess up the circle :-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a speed controller - three-phase to three-phase connected to the lathe.

If you run the lathe at full speed the park vector might be circular as expected.

Nice work!

Comment: More than that, it looks like the speed control operates by deleting and/or inverting entire cycles of the 3 phase supply! Very strange ... does the lathe allow a limited series of discrete speeds by any chance?

Comment: Sincerely I don't know if there are discrete speeds: I am reading the currents from afar, and didn't see the machine yet. 
So as I understand the speed controller is just "trimming" the sinusoidal waves.
The lathe is hightech (highly automatized and not the old manual ones), it looks strange they are using this solution. Or is it a common way to reduce motor speed? (I am mostly a software developer, sorry for the dumb questions)

Comment: @BrianDrummond Ward Leonardish?

Comment: Thank you everybody.